# Give a recursive definition of the set: $C:= \{ \frac{1}{3^2}, \frac{1}{6^2}, \frac {1}{9^2}, \frac{1}{12^2}, \frac{1}{15^2} \ldots \}$

Tags: recursion

> Question: Give a recursive definition of the set:
> $$C:= \left\{ \frac{1}{3^2}, \frac{1}{6^2}, \frac {1}{9^2}, \frac{1}{12^2}, \frac{1}{15^2}, \ldots \right\}$$

So I see this as the set $\left\{ \frac{1}{(3k)^2}\right\}$ for integers $k$ with $k \geq 1 $.

***Attempt:***
First the base case will be that $\frac{1}{3^2}$ is in the set.

Then if $x = \frac{1}{(3k)^2}$ is in the set, then

$$k = \sqrt{\frac{1}{9x}}$$

And so I am imagining that for $k+1$ we say that if $x$ is in the set then $$\frac{1}{(3 (\sqrt{1/(9x)} + 1))^2}$$ is also in the set. I see that this works for $x=1/9$ since plugging this value in gives us $\frac {1}{6^2}$.

I'm not at all confident this is the correct solution or if there is an easier way of seeing this problem. Any hints insights appreciated.

Comment: "the" recursive definition? Why is a recursive definition unique?

Comment: @Isomorphism fair, I guess I should write give "a" recursive definition.

Comment: If you wanted, you could potentially reduce the "dependencies on 3" to one place by saying it's the smallest set containing $\frac{1}{3^2}$ and closed under the binary operation $(x, y) \mapsto (x^{-1/2} + y^{-1/2})^{-2} = \frac{xy}{x + 2\sqrt{xy} + y}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_k$ be the $k$th element of the sequence. Then
$$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} = \frac{1/(3(k+1))^2}{1/(3k)^2}
= \frac{1}{((3k+1)/3k)^2}
= \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{3k}\right)^2},$$
and you can derive a recurrence formula for $a_{k+1}$ from that.